# is Java HashSet thread-safe for read only?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashset

If I have an instance of an HashSet after I ran it through Collections.unmodifiableSet(), is it thread-safe?

I'm asking this since Set documentation states that it's not, but I'm only performing read operations.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039470/are-final-unmodifiable-sets-thread-safe

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From the Javadoc:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally

Reading doesn't modify a set, therefore you're fine.

Comment: Except creating the HashSet and adding values to it, so it is usefully not empty, writes to it. So this answer is misleading.

Comment: Doing something like Collections.unmodifiableMap( /* call or code that creates a new HashMap here */ ) will create a populated, unmodifiable map (ensuring that no one ever changes it and threads only read from it).

Comment: @Raedwald I don't think this answer is misleading as it clearly says modifying the set, by modifying it doesn't mean we should add or remove or update any element within the set.

Answer (score 15):

`HashSet` will be threadsafe if used in a read-only manner.  That doesn't mean that *any* Set that you pass to `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` will be threadsafe.

Imagine this naive implementation of `contains` that caches the last value checked:

```
Object lastKey;
boolean lastContains;

public boolean contains(Object key) {
   if ( key == lastKey ) {
      return lastContains;
   } else {
      lastKey = key;
      lastContains = doContains(key);
      return lastContains;
   }
}
```

Clearly this wouldn't be threadsafe.

Comment: Changed from a Map example to a gross Set example to be more applicable to the question.

Answer (score 15):

It would be thread safe, but only owing to the fact that `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` internally publishes the target `Set` in safe manner (via the `final` field).

**Note that in general statements such as "read-only objects are always thread-safe" are not correct, since they don't take into account possibility of operation reordering.**

It's (theoretically) possible that, due to operation reordering, a reference to that read-only object will become visible to other threads before object is completely initialized and populated with data. To eliminate this possibility you need to publish references to the object in safe manner, for example, by storing them in `final` fields, as it's done by `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`.

Comment: +1, in general statements such as "read-only objects are always thread-safe" are not correct

Comment: Why final keyword makes this "read-only" thread-safe in regard to operation re-ordering? Does the JVM acts differently due to that?

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, `final` fields are the special case, see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5

Comment: Is it **documented** that the wrapper safely publishes? If not, it is unsafe to assume it does so. Although I can't imagine an implementation that didn't use a final field internally.

Answer (score 5):

Every data structure is thread-safe if you don't mutate it.

Because you have to mutate a HashSet in order to initialize it, it is necessary to synchronize once between the thread which initialized the set and all reading threads. You have to do it only *one* time. For example when you pass the reference to the unmodifiable set to a new thread which never touched it before.

Comment: Having dealt with toddlers, and what they grow into (Myself included during lapses); "I" didn't do it, it was that other pesky Thread.

Comment: That's not precisely true.  Take a look at my answer for an example where it's not true.  There is still mutation, but the user can't know that; it's mutation of encapsulated state.

Comment: @Mark Peters: Ok, it depends on the notion of mutation you apply. But for the standard notion of immutable as no memory location changes, it is true.

Comment: @jmg: By that definition `String` isn't immutable.

Comment: @Mark Peters: Btw, `String` isn't immutable under any reasonable definition of immutable, since methods like `toUpperCase()` depend on the current locale and return, depending on the locale, different things. Although `String` is clearly meant to be immutable.

Comment: @jmg: Huh?  What on earth does that have to do with immutability?

Comment: @Mark Peters: If you extend the definition of immutable from the naive one, being no memory location changes, to a more refined one like, no mutation can be observed from the outside. Then you have to avoid observable mutation, although there is no low-level memory mutation, as well. But we begin to be off-topic, the question of what is the right notion of immutability for object has no simple answer. Although, they are repeatedly proposed. In the end, it all comes to down the simple observation, that reading a global variable is a side-effect.

Comment: And immutability and side-effect freedom are more or less interchangable.

Comment: **That is so not true**. At least in Java. There is a difference between object you don't mutate and **immutable** object. Of these two only immutable objects automatically threadsafe. Object is immutable if: 1) it cannot be modified after construction 2) all its fields are final 3) this reference didn't escape during construction

Comment: @jmg String is most definitely immutable. Your odd conclusion is based on the fact that a particular method is not referentially transparent as it depends on a another implicit parameter. This is a property of the method, not the object itself.

Comment: @jmg also reading a global variable is not a side-effect, it is simply not referentially transparent. You may however read this variable and supply it as an argument, so reading the current Locale and supplying it to String.toUpperCase has made the String function referentially transparent.

Comment: @jmg @Mark_Peters String is not immutable but it is thread-safe. It has a cached hashcode whose setting has a race condition. This race is benign though as the hash function is referentially transparent.

Comment: I have no idea how this answer has so many up votes while giving such insidiously wrong advice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe for concurrent read access. Here is the relevant sentence from the documentation:

> If multiple threads access a hash set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally.

It states that you only need to synchronize if `at least one` thread modifies it.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: No, it does not state that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it is thread safe just because you run Collections.unmodifiableSet().  Even though the HashSet if fully initialized and you marked it as unmodifiable, doesn't mean that those changes will be visible to other threads.  Even worse, in the absence of synchronization, a compilier is allowed to re-order instructions, which could mean that not only does a reading thread see missing data but it can also see the hashset in a wierd state.  Therefore you will need some synchronization.  I believe one way around this is to create the hashset as final and to fully initialize it in the constructor.  Here is a good article on the JMM http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html.   Read the section on How do final fields work under the new JMM?

**The ability to see the correctly constructed value for the field is nice, but if the field itself is a reference, then you also want your code to see the up to date values for the object (or array) to which it points. If your field is a final field, this is also guaranteed. So, you can have a final pointer to an array and not have to worry about other threads seeing the correct values for the array reference, but incorrect values for the contents of the array. Again, by "correct" here, we mean "up to date as of the end of the object's constructor", not "the latest value available".**

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, Collections.unmodifiable views safely-publish the state of the set as it was when the unmodifiable wrapper was created (happens-before). Subsequent changes are not though, and the original reference should be abandoned.

Answer (score -2):

If the shared memory will never be changed, you can always read without synchronizing. Making the set unmodifiable will just enforce the fact that no writes can be made.

Comment: This is very, very wrong. There _must_ be a happens-before relationship of some kind between the original write and the read otherwise there is no guarantee that anything apart from the default value will be seen. While on x86 architectures, you will usually see something, that is not the same as any sort of guarantee.