# How to dynamically update a static lookup list

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, architecture

For brevity below is simplification of the actual problem. Let me know if something is not clear.

I have the following (pseudo) code which runs in some java service. User calls 'isItemPresent()' through service call (the freq. of call could be thousands per seconds).

```
public static Set<String> lookupSet= new HashSet<String>

void init()
{
   //read some million line text file or db and load lookupList
  lookupSet.add("item 2");
  lookupSet.add("item 5");
  lookupSet.add("item 9");
}

boolean isItemPresent(String checkItem)
{
   if(lookupSet.contain(checkItem))
       return true;

   return false;
}
```

`init()` is time consuming, and it takes few seconds to finish. The method is called only once when the app is first started.

**Problem:**

The 1 or 2 items in `lookupSet` could be added or removed few times a day: sometimes once a day or sometimes 50 times a day.

I want a way to update the `lookupSet` dynamically without reinitializing the entire app. The update should be in a way that `isItemPresent()` doesn't yield Null Pointer Exception for lookUpSet.

I wondered if it is possible to create a new LookupSet with the updated item list and swap the old LookupSet with the new one. Hence, it won't hinder `isItemPresent()` operation.
To implement that, do I need to spin another thread which will maintain updated `lookupSetLatest` and priodically the app's lookupSet will be updated/swapped by that.

I am not concerned that LookupSet is udpated late by few nano-seconds and isItemPresent() will return wrong result. I am critical that isItemPresent() doesn't break.

Let me know if need more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Use a concurrent Set, as described in the answer to this question: [Why there is no ConcurrentHashSet against ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992608/why-there-is-no-concurrenthashset-against-concurrenthashmap).

Also, `return lookupSet.contains(checkItem)` is more efficient than adding the `if` statement.