# What is the java provided class for ConcurrentModificationException in HashSet?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, synchronization

If we see in the oracle docs of HashSet, it states that while iterating thorough the Set, if we try to manipulate it, it throws ConcurrentModificationException. That is understood.

This is similar to what happens in case of ArrayList or HashMap. But if we see, there are alternate classes provided by Java such as CopyOnWriteArrayList and ConcurrentHashMap.

Why isn't there any such class for HashSet which tackles ConcurrentModificationException? Or even if it exist, please bring it to my notice. I am not aware of such classes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why there is no ConcurrentHashSet against ConcurrentHashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992608/why-there-is-no-concurrenthashset-against-concurrenthashmap)

Comment: `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and `ConcurrentHashMap` weren't introduced to prevent CME. They have their own purposes (and CHM was introduced as an upgrade over `Colletions.synchronizedMap()`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "ConcurrentHashSet", behaving the same way as a `ConcurrentHashMap`, you can just use [`Collections.newSetFromMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap-java.util.Map-) and pass a `ConcurrentHashMap` as argument.

There are other concurrent `Set` implementations: `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, `CopyOnWriteArraySet` for example.

Comment: Note the Java-8 alternative: `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`.

Comment: Why Map passed to the method newSetFromMap should be generalized as boolean for values?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR: A `ConcurrentModificationException` has nothing to do with threading!

The "concurrent" collections you mention in [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) are designed to provide fast and robust alternatives to `Collections.synchronizedXXX`. They are for use with multiple threads at the same time.

A `ConcurrentModificationException`, on the other hand, happens when you alter a collection whilst iterating it **in the same `Thread`**:

```
final List<String> list = ...
for(final String s : list) {
    list.remove(s);
}
```

This code will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` on the second iteration every time. Accessing a non-threadsafe `Collection` from multiple threads at the same time is Undefined Behaviour and may never produce a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Or it might just catch fire.

In order to avoid such behaviour, use an `Iterator` and ask it to modify the `Collection`:

```
final List<String> list = ...
final Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
while(iter.hashNext()) {
    final String s = iter.next();
    iter.remove();
}
```

To answer your completely unrelated question, in order to create a thread safe `Set` simply use the following:

```
final Set<String> threadSafe = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
```

With the addition of `Collections.newSetFromMap` the JDK designers did not see the point in creating a `ConcurrentHashSet` class.

### In summary

Do not use a concurrent `Collection` to get around the improper use of a `Collection` in a single threaded environment. It will at best be slower and at worst make your code behave in unexpected ways as the consistency guarantees provided by iterators for concurrent collections are much more relaxed.