# Better type than ConcurrentSkipListSet if I dont want the Comparable IF

Tags: java, set, java.util.concurrent, skip-lists

I am having a hot discussion with a colleague because he doesn't want to admit that it is better to use existing classes from the Java package than writing your own.

We want to access a set in a threadsafe way so that Iterators also work.

I found the class `ConcurrentSkipListSet` but it needs me to implement the `Comparable` interface, which we dont need. He argues that this is worse than writing the whole synchronized stuff. I say no.

Is there a better Java class than ConcurrentSkipListSet that doesn't make me implement `Comparable`?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` with dummy values?

Comment: You can use `ConcurrentHashMap` and get concurrent set from it afterwards. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6992643/1291150

Comment: hahaha, this is funny because this was the solution I used first but then he said when I use this, it will not be secure when using Iterators

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "secure". If you mean it won't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, it is secure. If you mean that the underlying set won't change while you're iterating, it isn't.

Comment: By the way, your colleague is half right: writing a dummy comparator for something that isn't meant to be ordered is a bad idea. However, writing all the synchronisation stuff by hand is also a bad idea (unless you're willing to put the time and effort in to make it bug-free). My advice would be to lower the temperature of that discussion first. Don't try to win the argument, try to find a solution that works and you're both happy with.

Comment: Wrapping a `ConcurrentHashMap` is really the only sane alternative.  It's not clear what guarantees you need on its iterators, though.  But trying to write your own concurrent collection type is almost certainly doomed to failure.

Comment: From checking the doc, `ConcurrentHashMap` provides the same iteration guarantees as `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, and the corresponding sets do too.  So if `ConcurrentSkipListSet` is good enough, so it `newSetFromMap(ConcurrentHashMap)`.

Answer (score 0):

To access a Set in a thread-safe way, it would be better to use [`Collections.synchronizedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-) and then synchronize access to the `Set` for iteration:

```
Set<Object> s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
synchronized (s) {
    Iterator<Object> i = s.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());
}
```

Comment: This works but it is brittle (it depends on everyone remembering to synchronize iterations) and will block modifications while iterating. Which may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: exactly. I was trying to evade this "write all synchronized stuff yourself" stuff