# HashSet Internally use HashMap or hastable (lower case) data structure?

Tags: java, spring, collections

I was going through the internal functionality of HashSet I came to know that it actually internally use HashMap. But in another post link reference given below, I noticed it is actually using hashtable in order to calculate the internal capacity and load factor.

I also have gone through this post but it doesn't help me much.

Now I am very much confused here is it using HasMap or hashtable internally.
please help me out with the proper clarification.

[Post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122981/does-hashset-and-hashmap-both-use-hashtable-or-hashtable-is-totally-different)

[Calculating load factor and internal capacity of a HashSet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-in-java/)

Comment: Perhaps you missed this in the second link you provided: "The HashSet class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table **which is actually a HashMap instance**"

Comment: It is combination of both. Everything, even if HashMap has internally HashTable. So hashset is made using both. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-sethashset-in-java/  but to summarize, you can call it HashTable in the end. Otherwise, hashing won't work

Comment: `Hashtable` and `HashMap` are both JDK classes that implement the hash table data structure. `HashSet` uses `HashMap` internally. It does not use `Hashtable`.

Comment: @Eran Thanks for the reply can you tell me the exact difference between Hashtable and hashtable (Lower case) ?

Comment: @RohitSharma `Hashtable` is a Java class. "hash table" does not refer to any specific Java class - it refers to a data structure.

Comment: @Eran ok I got it now thanks again.