# Java - Program got stucked in TreeSet.add()

Tags: java, multithreading, treemap, treeset

I have multi threads that want to put a value in a `TreeSet<Long>`, in a part of code. The values are almost unique because they are `System.nanoTime()`. I clean the `TreeSet`s periodically. Problem is that sometimes my threads got blocked in `TreeSet.add()` function. I used jconsole to watch thread states, threads are in `RUNNABLE` state and the stack trace shows this:

```
java.util.TreeMap.put(TeeMap.java:567)
java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
... //my program stack trace
```

I'm using jdk 1.7.0_60 for running program. Also I should mention in this situation cpu usage become 100%. My question is why the threads got blocked and how can I fix the situation? I looked at TreeMap code, but I didn't figure out problem, but I think problem relates to while loop in `TreeMap.put()`.

Comment: And what; may I ask; have you used to synchronize access to the `TreeSet`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider no, it is not. is that the problem?

Comment: Unless a `Collection` is explicitly designed as thread safe it cannot be accessed by multiple threads without a memory barrier. What you have created is a data race - congrats.

Comment: For multithreading, please use a ConcurrentHashSet

Comment: @ArthurEirich no such thing...

Comment: At first I thought that what Boris the Spider wrote shouldn't be the matter. Then I understood that he may (and probably is) right - TreeSet probably uses some search tree. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree ;

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oops, my bad! Thought there was one since a ConcurrentHashMap exists.

Comment: Also: would you look into javadocs of TreeSet ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html ) you could read: Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a tree set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally.

Comment: Last, but not least: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set) - it will be quite useful for you.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992608/why-there-is-no-concurrenthashset-against-concurrenthashmap#6992643) may help you

Comment: thanks guys, my bad! I'v got it :)

Comment: I understand that TreeSet is not threadsafe. But that would only create inconsistent state right? Why would it get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comments, the problem is that `TreeSet` is not thread safe and if we want to modify it (add or remove data) in multi threads, it must be synchronized externally.

Comment: Or, if performance is a concern (or, really even if it's not) you could use a [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) or [`Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap(java.util.Map)).

Comment: Surprisingly using `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())` caused `ConcurrentModificationException`! At the end I used `ConcurrentSkipListSet`

Comment: That exception does not mean what you think it means.