# Program got stuck at TreeMap.put

Tags: java, multithreading, treemap

I have an enterprise application which was eating so much of CPU. As dug further into thread dump, I see the threads that are eating so much CPU is stuck at `TreeMap.put`. I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739313/java-program-got-stucked-in-treeset-add) due to the same problem.

I understand people mentioned there that TreeMap is not thread safe. But what I don't understand is, not having ThreadSafe might cause inconsistent results. But why it holds the CPU?

Comment: Are you accessing the `TreeMap` from multiple threads? Thread-safety only concerns accessing the same object/state from multiple threads.

Comment: Also, how many elements are in the `TreeMap`? How long does a single `TreeMap#put` call take? How often do you call `put()`?

Comment: Unsynchronized multithreaded writes can corrupt a TreeMap to the point of forming infinite loops. [External explanation.](https://ivoanjo.me/blog/2018/07/21/writing-to-a-java-treemap-concurrently-can-lead-to-an-infinite-loop-during-reads/)

Comment: Just as an fyi: `HashMap` or `LinkedList` may also form infinite loops, e.g. when 2 threads change the `next` or `prev` references to form a cycle. And there are probably a couple of other collections or maps that suffer from the same. General rule of thumb: don't do unsynchronized parallel access to non-thread-safe data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multithreaded access to an unsynchronized `TreeMap` can not only cause inconsistent data to be seen, but can actively lead to [infinite loops](https://ivoanjo.me/blog/2018/07/21/writing-to-a-java-treemap-concurrently-can-lead-to-an-infinite-loop-during-reads/).

Infinite loops can, of course, take infinite amounts of time.  So really, really don't have multithreaded access to a `TreeMap`.  Use a concurrent implementation like `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, or synchronize properly.