# Java cuncurent Set/Queue/etc for read/write

Tags: java, set

I get String value from client and if this value does not fit my parameters  I add this value to my `Set<String>`. And every 10 min in scheduled method I get this values and try perform actions on them and remove from Set. I need Set in which I write and read values. Wrute one methos and read another method. I need cuncurent  Set or queue for it.

I try this:

```
private CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

But I found that CopyOnWriteArrayList has large overhead. How can I write and read String values in java the object of a joint access?

Comment: Have you looked into [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)? You can use it like a set but just setting the keys.

Comment: I have 1 value String. HashMap has 2 - key value. And I need unuque values

Comment: Refer to this question: ["Why there is no ConcurrentHashSet against ConcurrentHashMap

"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992608/why-there-is-no-concurrenthashset-against-concurrenthashmap)