# Is there a way to check if a Stream contains all collection elements?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, contains

For example, I need something like:

```
Collection<String> collection = /* ... */;
Stream<Object> stream = /* ... */;
boolean containsAll = stream.map(Object::toString).containsAll(collection);
```

Of course, I could accumulate all elements of the stream into another `Collection` using `collect()` method and the call `Collection.containsAll()`, but what if the stream is too big and it is inefficient to process all its elements?

Comment: Personally I think it's actually better to go with `Set<String> temp = source.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(toSet());
boolean containsAll = temp.containsAll(collection);`

Comment: @OusmaneD. What if *the stream is too big* as OP assumes? Imagine the case when the `stream` is lazily generated and not all elements are persisted in the memory. E.g. using `Files::lines`  you can process *huge* files even though they could not fit in your memory. Collecting into a set will cause `OutOfMemoryError` in such a case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(collection);
boolean containsAll = set.isEmpty() || stream.map(Object::toString)
                                             .anyMatch(s -> set.remove(s) && set.isEmpty());
```

---

The solution might look confusing, but the idea is straightforward:

1. In order to prevent multiple iterations over `collection` we wrap it into a `HashSet`. (In case your `stream` is a parallel one, then you will have to use a concurrent hash set. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992643/10584605) for more details)
2. If the `collection` (or `set`) is empty then we return `true` without processing the `stream`
3. For each entry of `stream` we try to remove it from `set`. In case the result of `Set::remove` is `true` (hence it was contained by `set`) and the `set` is empty after removal, we can conclude that `stream` contained all the elements of initial `collection`.
4. The terminal operation `Stream::anyMatch` is a short-circuiting one. So it will stop iterating over `stream` once the `set` is empty. In worst case we will process the entire stream.

---

Perhaps this is a bit more readable form:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(collection);
boolean containsAll = set.isEmpty() || stream.map(Object::toString)
                                             .filter(set::remove)
                                             .anyMatch(__ -> set.isEmpty());
```

---

If the `collection` can contain duplicates and there is a requirement to check if `stream` contains all of them, then we will need to maintain a concurrent map of counters.

```
Map<String, AtomicLong> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
collection.forEach(s -> map.computeIfAbsent(s, __ -> new AtomicLong()).incrementAndGet());
boolean containsAll = map.isEmpty() || stream.map(Object::toString)
                                             .filter(map::containsKey)
                                             .filter(s -> map.get(s).decrementAndGet() == 0)
                                             .filter(s -> map.remove(s) != null)
                                             .anyMatch(__ -> map.isEmpty());
```

The code slightly changed but the idea is the same.

Comment: Seems like you could also wrap it in a `List` to support checking if the stream contains multiple instances of an element. `List.remove` would return true until all copies are removed.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder Actually, this is a very interesting case. For the sake of simplicity I ignored that in my solution. But using `List` we'll loose the performance boost `HashSet` offers.

Comment: You could just check if the original collection is a `Set` and wrap it in `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList` in that case. This map count preprocessing seems like a trade-off, it might be faster for huge non-`Set` collections but probably worse for small ones.

Comment: This makes sense. Programming is all about trade-offs. Different data structures are suitable for different cases. It is still up to software engineer to pick the one which fits better the task he/she tries to resolve.

Comment: This blew my mind. I never thought if using stream like this. Thanks a lot. 
From a college student

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of how big the `Stream` is, you will have to process all of its elements if it does not contain all the elements of the `Collection`.

You could save processing time if a small prefix of the `Stream` contains all the elements of `Collection`, and the `Collection` is much smaller than the `Stream`.

```
boolean containsAll = 
    stream.map(Object::toString)
          .filter(s -> collection.contains(s)) // it would be wise to convert collection to a Set
          .limit(collection.size())
          .count() == collection.size();
```

Note that if the `Stream` may contain multiple copies of the same element of the `Collection`, you may have to add a `.distinct()` operation after the `filter()`.

Comment: I don't really understand the benefit of not using `collect` over any other operation(`count`) in this case. Since the stream processing for the complete elements would anyway take place(worst case), is there a possible optimization to get away with that much of memory being used?

Comment: @Naman would it process all the elements if, for example, the stream has 1000000 elements but all the elements of the Collection appear in the first 50 elements of the Stream? Of course, if not all the elements of the Collection appear in the Stream (or if the last of them appears near the end of the Stream), this solution wouldn't help.

Comment: What if the stream has some null entries? If the stream and collection are sorted, will it be faster to process _containsAll_?

Comment: @Eran By _containsAll_ I meant your method, finding if a collection contains all elements of a stream. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Paul I misunderstood your question. If the Stream and Collection are sorted, it should be possible to make an efficient solution (that doesn't process the entire Stream) even if the Stream doesn't contain all elements of the Collection, since we can identify the point in the Stream after which there can be no more elements that belong to the Collection. This can be done with `takeWhile`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Set from `Collection<String>` to make search operation faster `O(1)`

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(collection);
```

Then use `allMatch` to check every item in stream contains in set or not

```
boolean containsAll = stream.map(Object::toString)
                            .allMatch(s -> set.contains(s));
```

---

**Another way :**

Filter by not contained in set and use `limit(1)` for optimization

```
boolean isContains = stream.map(Object::toString)
                           .filter(s -> !set.contains(s))
                           .limit(1)
                           .count() > 0;
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. If set contains ("foo", "baa"), and your stream contains 100 x "foo", your function returns the wrong solution.