# Are final unmodifiable sets thread safe?

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety

The [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet(java.util.Set)) are not clear about this: are unmodifiable sets thread safe? Or should I worry about internal state concurrency problems?

```
Set<String> originalSet = new HashSet<>();
originalSet.add("Will");
originalSet.add("this");
originalSet.add("be");
originalSet.add("thread");
originalSet.add("safe?");
final Set<String> unmodifiableSet = Collections.unmodifiableSet(originalSet);
originalSet = null; // no other references to the originalSet

// Can unmodifiableSet be shared among several threads?
```

I have stumbled upon a piece of code with a static, read-only `Set` being shared against multiple threads... The original author wrote something like this:

```
mySet = Collections.synchronizedSet(Collections.unmodifiableSet(originalSet));
```

And then every thread access it with code such as:

```
synchronized (mySet) {
  // Iterate and read operations
}
```

By this logic only one thread can operate on the Set at once...
So my question is, for a unmodifiable set, when using operations such as *for each*, `contains`, `size`, etc, do I really need to synchronize access?

Comment: The unmodifiable set cannot be modified by any thread e.g. you cannot add nor remove anything from the set, but the threads may modify the state of the elements of the set, which probably needs to be synchronized.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is write, it depends on the containing elements, if they are immutable, then no thread synchronizations is required, for example in your provided sample the set contains `java.lang.String`s which are immutable, so you can remove syncrhonzations.

Comment: Is that so? How can one be sure that a decorator object is thread safe without knowing anything about decorated object's implementation? For performance or some other unanticipated reason, is it not possible that wrapped Set will modify its internal state at arbitrary times? I suppose that this is not the case with a simple HashSet but custom implementations might be more complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's an unmodifiable `Set<String>`, as per your example, then you're fine; because `String` objects are immutable.  But if it's a set of something that's not immutable, you have to be careful about two threads both trying to change the same object inside the set.

You also have to be careful about whether there's a reference somewhere to the `Set`, that's not unmodifiable.  It's possible for a variable to be unmodifiable, but still be referring to a `Set` which can be modified via a different variable; but your example seems to have that covered.

Answer (score 2):

Objects that are "de facto" immutable are thread safe. i.e. objects that never change their state. That includes objects that could theoretically change but never do.
However all the objects contained inside must also be "de facto" immutable.
Furthermore the object only starts to become thread safe when you stop modifying it.
And it needs to be passed to the other threads in a safe manner. There are 2 ways to do that.

1.) you start the other threads only after you stopped modifying your object. In that case you don't need any synchronization at all.

2.) the other threads are already running while you are modifying the object, but once you completed constructing the object, you pass it to them through a synchronized mechanism e.g. a ConcurrentLinkedDeque. After that you don't need any further synchronization.